# Call action from Redux store, to change React component state

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I have the following action, making an asynchronous GET request:

```
export const getPolls = () => {
 return async dispatch => {
    try {
        const polls = await serv.call('get', 'poll');             
        dispatch(setPolls(polls));
        dispatch(removeError());
    } catch (err) {
        const error = err.response.data;
        dispatch(addError(error.message));
    }
  }
}
```

Then, in component Polls, I want to be able to call this action, so I can show the list of Polls. To do this, I pass it on to this component's props:

```
    export default connect(store => ({    
       polls: store.polls
    }), {
    getPolls
    })
    (Polls);
```

And access it through `const {getPolls} = props;`

I am using React Hooks to create and change the Polls component state. Like this:

```
const Polls = (props) => {

    const {getPolls} = props

    const [polls, setPolls] = useState([])   

    useEffect(() => {
        const result = getPolls()
        console.log(result)
        setPolls(result)
    }, [])        
    
    const pollsList = polls.map(poll => (<li key={poll._id}>{poll.question}</li>))

    return (
        <div>                
            <ul className='poll-list'>{pollsList}</ul>
        </div>
    )    
}
```

With this code, I'm not able to get the polls. When I console.log the result from calling getPolls(), I can see I'm obtaining a Promise. However, since getPolls() is an async function, shouldn't this be avoided? I believe the problem has something to do with the way I'm using React Hooks, particularly useEffect, but I can't figure it out.

Thank you.

Comment: `async` functions return a `Promise` of the resolved value.  If your function is `return 5;` you get `Promise<number>`.

Comment: Why does your component have a `polls` state? aren't you storing the polls in redux?

Comment: @azium is right.  Delete your `useState`, change your `useEffect` to `useEffect(() => { getPolls();}, [])`, and access `polls` from `props`.  All you need to be doing in your component is *call* `getPolls()`.  The results of calling it will be reflected in the `polls` variable from `connect`.

Answer (score 0):

> When I console.log the result from calling getPolls(), I can see I'm obtaining a Promise. However, since getPolls() is an async function, shouldn't this be avoided?

You have a fundamental misunderstanding of `async` functions.  `async` and `await` are just syntaxes that help you deal with `Promise`s.  An `async` function [always returns a `Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#return_value).  In order to get an actual value, you would have to `await` the value from inside another `async` function.

But your `getPolls()` function is not a function that returns the polls.  It doesn't return anything.  It fetches the polls and calls `dispatch` with the data to store the polls in your redux store.

All that you need to do in your component is *call* `getPolls` so that this code is executed.  Your `connect` HOC is subscribing to the current value of `polls` from `store.polls` and the `polls` prop will update automatically when the `getPolls` function updates `store.polls` (which it does by calling `dispatch(setPolls(polls))`).

Your component can be simplified to this:

```
const Polls = (props) => {

    const {polls, getPolls} = props;  

    // effect calls the function one time when mounted
    useEffect(() => {
        getPolls();
    }, [])        
    
    const pollsList = polls.map(poll => (<li key={poll._id}>{poll.question}</li>))

    return (
        <div>                
            <ul className='poll-list'>{pollsList}</ul>
        </div>
    )    
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Everything is clear now.